# Client Side Graphing Tool that supports saving of the Graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot, gchart

I'm trying to find a graphing tool that runs clients side that will allow me to plot some data and then save the grpah. I have Tried FLOT http://code.google.com/p/flot/ but it does not support saving of the graph. I have tried gChart http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html but it does not support x/y plotting in a date format (and is not as interactive as FLOT).

I need to plot X (date or date time) to Y (some number). and be able to save the graph when done.

Any other charting / graphing tools out there? I like FLOT, but I just can't find a way to save the graph. (Something interactive and that works with dates along the X axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using HighCharts, check it out at http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend RGraph:

http://www.rgraph.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Flash I've had a lot of luck with [XML/SWF Charts](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/). It's not Open Source, but a license was only about $50 USD. You can right click and save the charts as JPEGs, BMPs, or PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you mean by save is to save it as an image. If so, then that is pretty simple to do with canvas. If you use a library like flot, you should be able to save the canvas image it draws on with a library like [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/). The only problem is that it won't work with IE earlier than 9, because previous versions use VML and don't actually support the canvas tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197468/how-to-save-a-jquery-flot-graph-to-a-png-or-orther-image-formate

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly a *client side* graphing tool as you asked for, because the graphs are rendered to images by Google's servers, but if you were looking for a client side solution just to save yourself from having to do image processing on **your** server, then I'd recommend the [Google Chart API](https://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

(or *Google Chart Tools / Image Charts (aka Chart API)* as it now seems to be called)

[image] [save](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=150x100&chbh=15,10&chd=t2:10,20,30,20,70,80|20,10,5,20,30,10|10,0,20,15,60,40,30&chds=0,120&chco=224499,009900&chm=D,76A4FB,2,0,3|N,FF0000,-1,-1,10)

[image] [save](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=s%3aUf9a&chs=250x100&chl=January|February|March|April)

[image] [save](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x100&chd=s%3aithankYouGodformostthisamazingdayforthel&chxt=x,y&chxl=0%3a|Apr|May|June|1%3a||50+Kb)

Renders directly to PNG, so you don't have to do anything clever to be able to save the graph.

Downside is that the graphs are not interactive, so if you really need that, this simple solution wouldn't be for you.