# Export Jquery chart to csv,pdf and excel

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, highcharts

Does any of the Jquery chart extensions provide chart to excel / pdf/ csv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Highcharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/) does have an [**export**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#exporting) option.  With the export option you can save the chart in one of the following formats: PNG image, JPEG image, PDF document, or SVG vector image.  With some additional code and work, you can also save it to a server and then use it in a more complicated document.

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to think so:

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/save-image-js.php

[How to save a jQuery FLOT Graph to a .png or orther image formate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197468/how-to-save-a-jquery-flot-graph-to-a-png-or-orther-image-formate)

Did you even try searching before posting?

Comment: Thanks Raoul,  The requirement is like convert chart to excel / pdf/ csv.