# Howto export jQuery flot graphs as images?

Tags: jquery, flot, imagesource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save a jQuery FLOT Graph to a .png or orther image formate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197468/how-to-save-a-jquery-flot-graph-to-a-png-or-orther-image-formate)

Is it possible to save graphs build with [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) as images?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with HTML5-capable browsers, flot outputs graphs to a <canvas> element. The canvas element has a fairly widely-supported ToDataURL() method that you can use to write the canvas to a URI scheme string to use as an image source.  What you do from the string from there is up to you, but [MDN provides an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Canvas#Saving_a_canvas_image_to_a_file) of saving the image, at least in the case of Firefox. At the very least you can create a new image element on your document and set its src to the result string, then allow a user to save the image.

Coming down the pipe as of this May is a new HTML 5 specification for [canvas.ToBlob()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-toblob) but that will take quite some time before it's supported. Last I read, no one has yet implemented it, as there's a bit of a waiting game until the specification is clearer and more finalized.

Comment: works great! in python, I can use base64.b64decode([chart data]) to get the image, then save it. It comes out as a nice png with alpha.

Comment: what about a bar graph that has a legend that HTML?

Comment: You should start a new question for your issue. This question is for discussion of saving graphs built with the flot library.